# Cant instanciate new object of class reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the code below, i try to create (in method createNewCharacter()) a new Character object containing all Character properties (obj.name, obj.image, obj.strength...) and methods.

But, when I console.log(firstCharacter), i don't have the excpected object but the object below :

[screen capture of the object created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lngwD.png)

Could someone save my life :D ? I'm a React beginner so tell me if i did bad baaaad things please.

Thank you

In my **App.js** file:

```js
// Character Class
class Character extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      image: '',
      strength: 0,
      health: 0,
      luck: 0,
      lvl: 0,
      progress: 0
    }
  }

}

//App Class with render
class App extends Component {
  //Here, some code is running
}
```

In my **Arena.js** file, where i try to create my character :

```js
import Character from './App';

class Arena extends Component {
    
  // Instancie un nouveau perso
  createNewCharacter = (charactersFDB) => {
        var firstCharacter = new Character(charactersFDB.name, charactersFDB.image, charactersFDB.strength, charactersFDB.health, charactersFDB.luck, charactersFDB.lvl, charactersFDB.progress)
   }  

  //Here, some code is running

}
```

Comment: Maybe you have to export your Character Class? why the second snipet don't output an error?

Comment: I've imported my input class at the top of Arena.js I modify my question ;)

Comment: did you read react docs ? it seems you're missing some basic concepts ( what are props, what are states, what does it mean to render a component, ... )